# Geb testing of directly inserted link in address bar

Tags: grails, groovy, geb

I have an application developed in ggts with grails/groovy and there are users with different roles. I want to test if a user can access some parts of the application by directly inserting link into address bar. So, where is my problem? When I test my application on localhost, everything is OK. But when I want to test through `http://shopapp` then it isn't OK. The application is the same.

Here is my code:

LoginSpec.groovy

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec  

import spock.lang.*  

import pages.*  


@Stepwise  
class LoginSpec extends GebReportingSpec {  


    def "opage"() {  
        when:  
    to LoginPage  
        loginUser()  
        acceptButton.click()  
        then:  
        to ProductPage  
}  
}
```

ProductPage.groovy

```
package pages  

import geb.Browser  

import grails.util.Holders  


class ProductPage extends ScaffoldPage {  

    def config = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config

    static url = {config.grails.serverURL + "/shop/catalog/show/123"}  



    static at = {  
        waitFor { title ==~ /Products/ }  
        title ==~ /Products/  

    }  


        static content = {  

        }  


    }
```

config.grails.serverURL should be `http://shopapp`.

When I start the test, it opens `http://shopapp/login`, the user logs in and the home page opens. But then it stays on home page. It should go to `http://shopapp/shop/catalog/show/123` because I want to test if a user can access a product by directly inserting a link into address bar.

Please help, I don't have any more ideas. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The static url property should be a string, not a closure:

```
static url = config.grails.serverURL + "/shop/catalog/show/123"
```

Comment: I tried this and I get ` You attempted to use a method 'config' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar. @ line 19, column 15. static url = config.grails.serverURL + '/shop/catalog/show/123'`